# bootstrap tab doesn't add active class to link

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

do I need to do extra step? I wish my tab will be highlighted but it doesn't work although I use js to call, like this `$(this).tab('show')`

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/131/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code working:

```
$('.stat-number-desc').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show');
        $('.stat-wrap').find('.stat-number-desc').css('background-color','none');
        $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    })
```

Change blue for color do you want.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/132/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are calling 'this' in reference to the div, not the tab. You need to use the class name of the tabs themselves.